# Properly use WinInet in parallel thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety, wininet

I am writing a user-interfaced program that parses Google results page for finding stuff from shopping sites, in particularly, from Amazon.

Because it has user interface, it, obviously should make all internet actions in parallel thread, or the program will be hanged.

I am not actually good in multithreading, and obviously do it not correctly, in example:

```
HINTERNET internet;
int GetRequest(wchar_t* url, char *buffer, int bufersize)
{
int read = 0;

if (internet)
{
DWORD dwBytesRead;

HINTERNET hu = InternetOpenUrl(internet, url, L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", wcslen(L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"), INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);

if (hu)
{
  int err = GetLastError();

  for (;;)
  {
    char b[1024] = {};
    BOOL bRead = InternetReadFile(hu, buffer + read, sizeof(b), &dwBytesRead);

    read += dwBytesRead;
    if (dwBytesRead == 0)
      break;
  }
}
else
  read = -1;

InternetCloseHandle(hu);

}
else
 read = -2;

return read;
}
```

Usage

```
int status;
void run();

int main()
{
internet = InternetOpen(L"My user agent", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, 0); 
std::thread t(run);
t.detach();

while(status==0){}

if(status==1)
{
char *response = new char[1024*1024*2];
MessageBoxA(NULL, response,"Aga",MB_OK);
}
else
 MessageBoxA(NULL, "Error","Aga",MB_OK);

delete[] response;
status = 0;
return 0;
}

void run()
{
char *buffer = new char[1024*1024*2]; // 2mb buffer
int read = GetRequest(L"https://www.google.com/search?q=lolkek", buffer, 1024*1024*2); // or www.search.yahoo.com
strcat_s(response,1024*1024*2,buffer);
delete[] buffer;
if(read>=0)
status = 1;
else
status = -1;
}
```

Actually it works perfectly. The program does what I want.

**But** I faced an issue: when the program is running, I open Chrome, and some buttons in Amazon’s site doesn’t work. In particularly, sell button in product page - by clicking on it, nothing is happens, closing my program and now that button opens login page. Also, seems it breaks data in some google sheets, even, when program works only with Yahoo.

Program **does not** access amazon.com or any shopping site directly. It has been connecting to google.com, but now even only to search.yahoo.com.

Has anyone faced something like that? Is the problem in not correct multithreading? Maybe I should change internet flags(not exactly to asynchronous, but, maybe add `INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE` or something like that?

---

I have one assumption: it could happened because three instance of program was run at one time. Also the tabs with Google Sheets that was corrupted was opened in Chrome, when the program was running.

Comment: *"Is the problem in not correct multithreading?"* - Make your test program single-threaded and observe the behavior. That may answer this question anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable ok, I’ll try.

Comment: No.  You're seeing these web sites protecting themselves against suspicious bot traffic.

Comment: @HansPassant I don’t access amazon.com or any shopping site directly. I have been connecting to Google, but now even only to Yahoo.

Comment: I'm sorry that you cannot reproduce your problem with the code you gave. Could you provide create a [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example to help us reproduce your problem?

Comment: @ZhuSong unfortunately no. Currently I tend to believe that the problem is in running several instances of the program. I am researching it now, and rather will give own answer on this question